# Meaning of いまい in this sentence

Tags: grammar, volitional-form

> こんな嵐の中、まさかここまで郵便を届けにくるやつは**いまい**、と思っているにちがいない。
> He was surely thinking that nobody would deliver mail here in a storm like this. (my TL)

I cannot work out what いまい is doing in this sentence.

I've come across まい as a negative volitional form before, but I'm assuming it is attached to the verb いる here and that doesn't seem like a verb you could make volitional.

To me it would make perfect sense if I replaced いまい with いない (is this true?), so maybe it's just a typo.

Comment: Also, いる + 〜まい should become いるまい, not いまい.

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/まい-632809

Comment: Does this answer your question? [~すまいて after a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97681/%e3%81%99%e3%81%be%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6-after-a-verb) With 一段 verbs ～まい attaches to the 連用形 usually rather than the 終止形 (though I think that's still an option)

Comment: This まい is for negative *inference*, not negative *volition*, so it means the same thing as いないだろう.

Comment: @Kaskade Here いまい and いるまい are interchangeable. The former is considered more tranditional or canonical, but in reality the latter is more common. See my answer in the link.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for the correction. Shouldn't have claimed it so boldly...